# Can I record my xbox 360 gameplay if it is connected to my network?

Tags: xbox-360

I have it connected to my laptop with an ethernet cable.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the Xbox One, the 360 has no recording features built in to the system. You need a 3rd party piece of [hardware](https://www.elgato.com/en/gaming/game-capture-hd) in order to record gameplay.

If you have the 360 playing through to your laptop (If I am reading that correctly) you would need [recording software](http://mirillis.com/en/products/action.html) that will let you record the screen.